# Grey bar appearing over full screen apps on external monitor

Tags: fullscreen, dual-screen

This happens in VLC, iTerm, Chrome, maybe others where a grey-ish bar appears where the menu bar would normally be and if I mouse over it the menu bar appears. In Chrome this sometimes appears when I have created a new window on my main screen, make it fullscreen, and move it to the second display, but if I exit full screen and re-enter full screen it works, but not for VLC or iTerm. Any ideas on how to fix this?

The third chrome image is what it looks like when it's working correctly (and the mouse is hovering to shown the menu bar).

> [image: VLC]

> [image: Chrome, menu bar hidden]

> [image: Chrome, menu bar shown]

> [image: Chrome, menu bar fixed]

> [image: iTerm]

Comment: There are apps that people use to remove the transparent effect of the menu bar. This might be a case of one of those apps behaving badly. Do you have one installed?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, do you have an example? The only time I can remember seeing anything related is the translucent menu bar option in the wallpaper settings and the result is the same with that option on and off.

Comment: Just to confirm, only on the external monitor?

Comment: Correct. Never on the laptop display.

Comment: Sometimes the Video files have a interrupt (like for advertisement) that will cause that, so what is the source of your videos.

Comment: This is VLC playing a DVD or mpeg file. Chrome will do this with and without video content.

Comment: The screenshot you r showing is not full screen (left to right) (or is that the video limit)?

Comment: That's the source aspect ratio. If I stretch it it would fill the black and not the grey. I will upload some more examples tonight.

Comment: I think this is a known behaviour. I've noticed it to be there since Mavericks. It's probably to highlight that the window is not in use probably.

Comment: @jash Jacob, it's there even when that app/screen is in use.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about it, you could remove the second menu bar in the settings. It should fix the problem.

http://www.mactrast.com/2013/10/disable-second-menu-bar-os-x-mavericks/